# Index order break Foundry dataset from fusion sheet

Tags: dataset, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-fusion-sheet

I have created Palantir Foundry dataset from the Fusion sheet. But rows are not in the correct order as the Fusion sheet. What is the correct way to do it?

**Fusion sheet data**

[image: Fusion sheet data]

**Dataset created from Fusion sheet**

[image: Dataset created from Fusion sheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark doesn't preserve any ordering and Fusion does not try to keep row orders when exporting to a dataset. In general, row orders in Foundry datasets should not be relied upon. You might be able to work around this by adding an index column.

**Previous edit:**

I had tested this and the sync kept the order on the output dataset correctly without any particular configuration. After digging a bit more it seems I was just lucky.

[image]

[image]